# Normalizing with ffmpeg-normalize, slight variations in sound

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, spotify

I have some flacs which I am trying to normalize for Spotify and Distrokid.

I got the guide from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1705712/is-ffmpeg-usable-with-audio-loudness-normalization#1705714)

```
ffmpeg-normalize inbound/*.flac -t -14 -lrt 11 -tp -1 -ext flac -c:a flac -of normalized/
```

Now the problem is ( before submitting to Distrokid ) that when listening to normalized versions there seems to be light deviations, like muffling, to the sound at half a second lenghts.

[Small sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/144CcRlMweCmOMzoqYfJ2UKBe0akIRPvt/view?usp=sharing), towards the end.

Now I'm asking for help because even though I can try different settings I still want to conform to Spotify normalization guide.

The Spotify guide is as follows:

```
Target the loudness level of your master at -14dB integrated LUFS 
and keep it below -1dB TP (True Peak) max. This is best for lossy 
formats (Ogg/Vorbis and AAC) and makes sure no extra distortion’s 
introduced in the transcoding process.

If your master’s louder than -14dB integrated LUFS, make sure 
it stays below -2dB TP (True Peak) to avoid extra distortion. This 
is because louder tracks are more susceptible to extra distortion 
in the transcoding process.
```

and

```
 ffmpeg version N-102727-g580e168a94-tessus
 ffmpeg-normalize v1.22.8
```

[Tracks now on Spotify.](https://spotify:track:019sn7wWCBW0vPSxE40Wio)

Comment: Have you looked at the ebur128 filter https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ebur128-1

Comment: ffmpeg-normalize was created to "normalize media files to a certain loudness level using the EBU R128"

Comment: The reason I mention it, is because it has a video option to visualise the `current loudness level and TP`. Maybe that's the issue with adding a P.S. - it distracts from the actual question.

Comment: to get loudness level and TP:  ffmpeg -nostats -i input.flac -filter_complex "ebur128=peak=true" -f null - 2>&1 | tail -20

Comment: For `visualising` it, I was thinking of `ffmpeg -hide_banner -nostats -i input.flac -filter_complex "ebur128=video=1:meter=12:gauge=m:peak=true:target=-14" -f matroska - | ffplay -hide_banner -nostats -autoexit -i - `

Comment: You might be able to normalize audio in Davinci Resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4/25: a Status update.

It indeed seems that ffmpeg-normalize is doing it's normalization which causes the variance in the sound. Rolf's visualizer clearly shows the problems arising when the normalizing changes the output graph. It's not about keeping the levels down enough but how that is achieved.

Normalizing the small sample doesn't cause the problem, but normalizing the full length does. I suspect changing the Range helps here. Targetting integrated LUFS -16 seems to help, but I am still ravaging through different parameters. I'll keep you updated.

5/20 Add:

It seems lowering the range parameter seems to help. I can use -14 LUFS without the dampening. Upon doing visualizations I can see why:

LUFS -14 Range 10:

[image: LUFS -14 Range 10]

LUFS -16 Range 10:

[image: LUFS -16 Range 10]

LUFS -14 Range 4:

[image: LUFS -14 Range 4]

I think I'll go with -14/4, but it's a bit a matter of taste, how silent you want the less loud bits to be.

PS: the song, support us and listen it in Spotify.

https://open.spotify.com/track/4Da8z21xH17Jw2iWB46tR6?si=fb106bc675ee496d

Comment: I have been trying to normalise some mp3 files to get a constant loudness when I shuffle them. I noticed a higher volume at the beginning of each song when a single instrument is played then gradually the volume decreases. It is really subtle but noticeable

`ffmpeg-normalize *.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k  -ext mp3 --target-level -14 --keep-loudness-range-target --progress
`
Any ideas?